# How can I deploy firebase queue to app engine and have it observe Firebase nodes?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send device-to-device notification via FCM which is not so trivial. I use Firebase as the database and by reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) have learned that I need to have an app server to communicate between clients and FCM. Also, I have found that Firebase queue can be used to observe the Firebase nodes and upon any change e.g, ChildAdded, send a notification to other related users on other devices via FCM.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to deploy Firebase queue to app engine; as I'm not that experienced with node.js and it seems that Firebase queue documents are all written with node.js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for someone who is new to node.js it was a bit of confusing cycle to understand whats going on , but I was able to upload a simple job which is pretty much the "[sanichat](https://github.com/mcdonamp/sanichat)" example of firebase-queue and it seems to be working.

Here's the job for anyone who might be struggling with the same issue:

```
// chat_message_sanitization.js

var Queue = require('firebase-queue');
var firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: 'path to the json file downloaded when setting up google services account',
  databaseURL: 'https://***your firebase***.firebaseio.com/'
});

var db = firebase.database();
var 

queueRef = db.ref('queue');
var messagesRef = db.ref('queue_messgs');

var options = {
  'specId': 'sanitize_message'
};

var sanitizeQueue = new Queue(queueRef, options, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
  // sanitize input message
  data.message = sanitize(data.message);

  // pass sanitized message and username along to be fanned out
  resolve(data);
});
```

I have been able to run it locally "node app.js" and deploying using "gcloud app deploy"

Cheers!